# Mongodb geospetial query with sanic-motor

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo, sanic

I am trying to use mongodb geospetial query with sanic-motor but it doesn't work.

Simple find with no arguments works well, and my query executes in mongo-db-compass.
My query :

```
await DataPoint.find({"location.cordinates": { '$nearSphere' : {'$geometry': { type: "Point", 'coordinates': [20.44974230, 44.8772 ] },'$minDistance': 0,'$maxDistance': 80}}})
```

I've got `AttributeError : 'dict' object has no attribute 'args'.`

Please help me.

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLT0N.png)

Comment: Can give us more info? And why ve you await, how do you print it, output example

Comment: Looks like sanic-motor is passing a dict as the request object. If I had to guess, maybe there is a version mismatch between your app and what that package supports? I'd suggest contacting the package developer.

Comment: Thank you @TheBrewmaster and Luis Bote for responses, i contacted the package supports but i got explanation of python dict.[ https://github.com/lixxu/sanic-motor/issues/13 ]